# How many companies are using which sharepoint version

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Is there a current survey/statistik how many companies are using which sharepoint version?

Someting like this?

```
Total companies: x
- using SP 2003: x%
- using SP 2007: x%
- using SP 2010: x%
```

Couldn't find a current (this year) one on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll find a specific report with such sales statistics (Microsoft's discretion may be limited only to their partnet/vendors). Alternatively, you can forage through various SharePoint industry posts to obtain the sales statistics (a few examples) -

1. [SharePoint sales help Microsoft reach record revenue](http://blog.snowbound.com/ecm/2027/sharepoint-sales-help-microsoft-reach-record-revenue/)
2. [Sales rocket for Microsoft SharePoint Server](http://www.zdnet.co.uk/news/enterprise-apps/2007/07/27/sales-rocket-for-microsoft-sharepoint-server-39288273/)
3. [Bill Gates Touts Strong Growth and Enterprise Adoption of Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/presspass/press/2008/mar08/03-02SPPTEnterpriseGrowthPR.mspx)